# How can I move my YouTube account from a Gmail to an Apps account?

Tags: google-workspace, youtube, google-account, migrate-data

I've already tried the steps [here](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1267449) but the last step isn't possible since there isn't a tooltip on the dashboard page.

I have a Gmail account (`me@gmail.com`) that has my YouTube channel with uploads/etc. I want to move all the data to my Google Apps account (`me@me.com`). I don't care if views/etc are kept. I want to be able to stop using my Gmail account for non-Gmail things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use that tool you must have [conflicting](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181526) user accounts.**

From the [support page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1267449) you listed:

> If you did not have a conflicting account, you won’t be able to use the automatic data moving tool. **For instance, you won’t be able to move data from an unrelated @gmail.com account to your Google Apps account.**

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNR2mLxxIg8) explains what a conflicting account is.

Comment: Is there another way to do it if you don't have a conflicting user account?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way - sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a bummer, but still a valid answer.